# Column names containing dots in Spectrum

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I created a customers table with columns has account_id.cust_id, account_id.ord_id and so on. 
My create external table query was as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE spectrum.customers
(
"account_id.cust_id" numeric,
"account_id.ord_id" numeric
) 
row format delimited
fields terminated by '^'
stored as textfile
location 's3://awsbucketname/test/';

SELECT "account_id.cust_id" FROM spectrum.customers limit 100
```

and I get an error as :

> Invalid Operation: column account_id.cust_id does not exists in
>   customers.

Is there any way or syntax to write column names like account_id.cust_id (text.text) while creating the table or while writing the select query?

Please help.

PS: Single quotes, back ticks don't work either.

Comment: why did you decide to ttry to put . in the column names?

Comment: What does `select * from SVV_EXTERNAL_COLUMNS` show?

Comment: were you able to find a solution ?